# Split a variable-length column in T-SQL without using a WHILE loop

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column in a table where the data varies in length. For some records, the length of the column is 8, for some records it's 20, for many records it's some number in between, NOT NECESSARILY divisible by four.

I've been asked to change this data to `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.` etc until I run out of numbers. So, for example if I have

```
12345678
```

I should change it to

```
1234.5678.
```

- If I have `12345`, I should change it to `1234.5`.
- `1234567890ABCDEFGH` becomes `1234.5678.90AB.CDEF.GH`

I can do this with a `WHILE` loop, but I try to stay away from looping in T-SQL and use set logic instead. I'm wondering, is there a way to do this that doesn't involve loops?

Comment: What is the maximum column length? 20? Also what version of SQL Server?

Comment: The maximum column length is 50, although currently I have no values longer than 20 characters. I'm using SQL Server 2008 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @val varchar(20) = '12345678'

SELECT RTRIM(COALESCE(
        STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@val+' ',5,0,'.'),10,0,'.'),15,0,'.'),20,0,'.'),
        STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@val+' ',5,0,'.'),10,0,'.'),15,0,'.'),
        STUFF(STUFF(@val+' ',5,0,'.'),10,0,'.'),
        STUFF(@val+' ',5,0,'.'),
        @val
        ))
```

Comment: I apologize for not responding to this for so long. I got dragged away to a different project and in the meanwhile this issue became a moot point. I appreciate your help anyway. I've marked your answer as "the answer" because I think it would've been the best answer if I still needed an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am unclear about whether/when the final period is included, but the following seems to do what you want:

```
select ((case when len(val) > 0 then substring(val, 1, 4) + '.' else '' end) +
        (case when len(val) > 4 then substring(val, 5, 4) + '.' else '' end) +
        (case when len(val) > 8 then substring(val, 9, 4) + '.' else '' end) +
        (case when len(val) > 12 then substring(val, 13, 4) + '.' else '' end) +
        (case when len(val) > 16 then substring(val, 17, 4) else '' end) 
       )
```

Comment: I apologize for not responding to this for so long. I got dragged away to a different project and in the meanwhile this issue became a moot point. I appreciate your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a numbers table to avoid hard coding a load of cases up to string length 50.

```
DECLARE @Nums TABLE(N INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO @Nums VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13)

UPDATE YourTable
SET    Val = STUFF((SELECT '.' + SUBSTRING(Val, N * 4 + 1, 4)
                    FROM   @Nums
                    WHERE  N <= ( LEN(Val) - 1 ) / 4
                    ORDER BY N
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16f1d/1)

Comment: I apologize for not responding to this for so long. I got dragged away to a different project and in the meanwhile this issue became a moot point. I appreciate your help anyway.